# Jquery mobile ajax call isnot working (Crossdomain)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, playframework-2.0

I have two projects running seperately one is a simple static HTML5 website hosted on  IIS which Iam evaluating  for my mobile application on port number **90**.

secondly I have a webserver running for services on port **9000** which returns `JSON` data (I use playframework2.0 for this).

In my static website I have a `HTML5` page which has the below `ajax` call to the service url.

```
$("#homePg").on('pageinit', function(event) {
 $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:9000/menu',
        success : function(response){
                alert('success'+response);
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error){
        alert('error'+xhr.responseText);
        }
      }); 
   });
```

everytime it goes to the error function, where as when I try the same url in the browser it works fine.

Am using `Jquery 1.7.1` and `jquery.mobile.1.1.1.js`

Have checked in firebug the URL loads properly but response is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript, a different port is treated as a cross domain call.  You will need to use jsonp.

I use the [jquery.jsonp](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) library to do this.

```
$.jsonp({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/menu',
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

    }
}); //end ajax
```

I would like to note that jsonp can only do `GET` requests, so if you need to pass any data, it has to be part of the query string.  If you are submitting data that has legal ramifications -- such as credit card data, you'd have to turn off your system logging so that the card numbers are not stored in the IIS logs.

You can also do jsonp calls with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/menu',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback"
});

function jsonpcallback(data) { 
    alert('success' + data);
}
```

I've never used the second method, so I am not even sure if this code will work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on cross-domain for different ports, though have tried both of the suggested solutions, for some reasons its still not working and its hard to give any reasons as there are no errors or any info logged on to the console.

Comment: That's interesting.  Have you tried multiple browsers to see if maybe there is a browser issue?  I know there can be problems with IE and any cross-domain requests depending on the security settings.  I developed my cross-domain solutions in chrome, which will show any errors around cross-domain traffic.

Comment: OH!  I just remembered that the Json you return has to be properly formatted to work with jsonp.  you have to put the callback around your json like this: `callback([myjson])`.  [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) is a resource that can help you figure out how to render your json.

Comment: looks like we are some wer closer.. I cam see the data returned when i use the first method ..but not sure why that is not able to called in success function.. have tried puttin `?callback` but no luck..any suggestions?

Comment: when I tried with callback ..I get to see this in my firebug http://192.168.0.10:9000/menu?callback=_jqjsp&_1345481026925= ... But unfortunately this isnt able to be load in my success function

Comment: Thanks for your time it is sorted :).. the service was the problem it should return with the callback function name the link which u posted really helped me ..Thank u once again