# How to reference to an uploaded img src in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am creating a responsive mobile website, and I want to be able to take and then upload a picture from the device. I have got this part working using

```
<form method="post" action="takephoto.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
</form>
```

Now, what I am having trouble with is, after I have selected the picture that I want to use I do not know how to reference it later in my code. The reason I need to is I am using a .js library which allows me to upload a picture of a ISBN barcode and the .js file will read this file and spit out the ISBN as text which I will do more with later. (maybe link this to a Google Books API)

This is where I am getting the barcode scanner .js from: http://badassjs.com/post/654334959/barcode-scanning-in-javascript

I am relatively new to all of this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037006/jquery-mobile-ajax-call-isnot-working-crossdomain) contains some useful information for you.

Use ajax to get the picture uploaded and in the response, return the `url` or "failed". Then you can use in your js code,

```
if(response=="failed"){
    //Handle upload failed
}
else {
    //Handle url. Here response is your url actually.
              // So to append the image to a given id, you would use,
    $("#append_to_id").append("<img src='"+response+"'>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the JavaScript library you are using is parsing an image on the page,
you have to show the image on the page after you have uploaded it.

So basically you need 4 steps to achieve this:

1. show an upload form (This is what you have done in the question);
2. grab the image uploaded in step 1 and save it to an accessible place
3. display the image on the screen
4. call get_barcode_from_image.js to parse it

Here's a piece of code for reference.  It contains all the 4 steps above.

```
<?php
// step 2: save the image
if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] == 0) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], 'u/barcode.jpg');
?>
<!-- step 3: show the image -->
<img src="u/barcode.jpg" id="barcode">
<script src="get_barcode_from_image.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<!-- step 4: parse the barcode -->
<button onclick='document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getBarcodeFromImage("barcode")'>scan</button>
<?php
}
?>
<!-- step 1: show the upload form -->
<form method="post" action="barcode.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name='a' value='b'/>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Of course you can use ajax or so to get better user experience, but the process won't change.